RTC super capacitor is discharging very fast
I am using a PCA85073A RTC in my design. On some boards, the supercapacitor discharges very fast (5V to 1.1V in half an hour.)
This happens when we turn off 5V_uC.
The circuit is given below.

All the signals on the right hand side are going to a microcontroller. On the I2C line one more device is connected. A 100K pullup is connected for RTC_INTP, RTC_SCl, RTC_SDA. Below is the block diagram of right hand side signals. All the signals are going to the microcontroller.
The FET RESET signal comes from the microcontroller.

When 5V_uC is off, the RTC runs the from supercapacitor.
The microcontroller is also off at that time. The clock output of the RTC will be in enabled state.
I am seeing only two paths for the super capacitor to discharge. One is via the MOSFET and the other via C260 (if C260 is shorted.)
Will the discharge happen via any other paths?
----
UPDATE There is a mistake in this question:
I discussed it with the system team and got a complete picture;
here's the improved new question.

Maybe reverse leakage through D64?  Perhaps try removing that component on one of the faulty boards and see if the cap holds up any better

There clearly is a path. What you have measured about the circuit? Also there is no info how exactly those signals on the right connect to other systems, and if these systems are powered or unpowered. And there is no explanation for the reset signal that controls the discharge FET. What is the purpose of the clock signal, how is it used and is it ever turned on or off?

Is the CLKOUT enabled?  Are there signals being output on the I2C lines?  These could result in significantly higher current draw from the IC, depending on what is on the other end of the lines (per p.38 of the datasheet).

@Justme,I updated the question

@Tony,When 5V_uC is off the RTC will be working from supercapacitor and the clock out will be enabled

@Confused - As commented on the answer below by Justme, it is too late to change this question, even if you did make a mistake in the details provided here. Another site member has kindly edited this question to remove the new question, leaving just the link to where you (correctly) posted it as a separate question. || Please do not change the question here any more. TY

This explains the issue.

When 5V_uC is off the RTC will be working from supercapacitor and the microcontroller is also off at that time.The clock output of the RTC will be in enabled state.

You can't feed logic signals or voltages into a MCU that is unpowered.
The MCU input protection diodes try to clamp the voltage that the RTC clock pin outputs to MCU, and current flows through the MCU protection diode to output 5VMCU node.

leaping ahead to a solution, or at least a test of the diagnosis, a diode in the RTC_CLK line to the MCU, and a new pullup to MCU_5V, would allow the RTC_CLK_IN to be pulled low through the diode, and be pulled high when the MCU is powered, and would isolate the MCU load when it's unpowered.

@Justme,sorry for the delay.May I know if I break the RTC signals from the controller when the controller is off,will it solve the issue

@Confused Which signals you mean? Why would you break all instead of the one that causes the problem?

@Justme,Signals I mean,(RTC_INTP,RTC_CLK,RTC_SCL,RTC_SDA).May I know how I will find which one is causing problem among this 4 signals.

@Confused I quoted the cause of the problem in my answer and it's being discussed in these comments. The only signal that's active when MCU is powered off is the square wave clock.

@Justme,got it.I will keep an analog switch in the RTC CLK path

@Justme,May K know connecting an analog switch in the RTC path will solve the issue. The switch will be powered with the same power supply of Microcontroller. So when the controller is off switch is open and RTC will be disconnected. Kindly share your thoughts.

@Confused It depends. It simply moves the problem of current leaking through IO protection of unpowered MCU to a problem of current leaking through IO protection of unpowered analog mux. Unless your mux can handle signals on inputs while unpowered.

Thank you .May I know how about using relay

@Confused why would you even consider a relay? Simply used the mux correctly or use a digital chip that can tolerate signals on input while unpowered.

I will go with mux which can tolerate the voltage

@Confused The mux can tolerate the voltage if you power it from the RTC battery.

@Justme,I think I got it MUX will be powered from RTC battery and MUX control will come from the Microcontroller. Correct me if I am s wrong

@Confused It's not wrong but the mux may come from MCU IO or just from the MCU supply that either is or is not present.

Can use this IC. TS5A3166 0.9-Ω SPST Analog Switch

@Confused Maybe, but the funny thing is, the analog port cannot have voltages unless the mux is powered, so you have to keep the mux powered from battery, but the digtal input allows control voltages even without mux being powered. It might be simpler to use a digital chip that allows voltages on input while powered.

By digital chip you mean something like this 74CBTLV1G125GW,125.Please correct me if I am wrong

@Justme,I updated the question.If you don't mind could you please check

@Confused You asked a question, it was answered, and accepted, with the info that was available back then. And you do not show what "5v_uc" and "VDD_5V_MCU" are. Please ask a new question.
